# Best practice for multiple native code library binding development?

Tags: java, ruby, eclipse, perl, netbeans

I am developing a native C library that needs bindings to Java (JNI) in both Oracle and Android NDK settings, Ruby, Python, and Perl.

I have written bindings in all these environments individually.  But is there any best practice wisdom for setting up such a project in Eclipse so that all the bindings compile automatically from a common C codebase?

If not Eclipse, then Netbeans?

I do realize that memory allocation within the library will need to be different for each language platform, but this appears manageable with macros.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linking languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271488/linking-languages)